# Entity Framework CTP5 Code-First: How do I specify the type of the discrimimator column in Table-Per-Hierarchy Mapping?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/14/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx) of the ADO.NET team shows in an example how to define Table-Per-Hierarchy Mapping in the Fluent API of Entity Framework Code-First. This is the (slightly simplified) example:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // more properties
}

public class DiscontinuedProduct : Product
{
    public DateTime DiscontinuedDate { get; set; }
}
```

... and the TPH mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .Map<Product>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("Current"))
    .Map<DiscontinuedProduct>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue("Old"));
```

`Type` is here obviously a "pure" discriminator column in the database table which has no related property in the model classes. That's fine and what I want.

If I let create the DB tables for this mapping, the column `Type` has in SQL Server the type `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Is there a way to configure the type of the discriminator column in the Fluent API?

For instance: I have a discriminator column `Type` with possible values `"A", "B" or "C"` to distinguish between my derived model classes. How can I configure that the column in SQL Server has type `varchar(1)`?

(I have tried to use simply a character value by setting for instance `m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue('A')` (note the single quotes). But this throws an exception telling me that a `char` type is not allowed as discriminator column.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EF team [**confirms here**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adonetefx/thread/9cc0e8e0-13d7-4f23-9fbb-98f9c7d4b2c3) that change the type of the discriminator column in TPH is not currently supported. This is something that they are looking into to see if they can enable it before the RTM.

That said, I showed how to change the column type to int in [**this article**](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) but like they confirm this is not fully supported for all types as of CTP5.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Yes, in the meantime I've changed the discriminator to a numeric type, similar to the example in your Blog post, in my case: `... .HasValue((byte)0)` which creates a `tinyint` column in the DB. Unfortunately I'm facing now other problems with TPH. One is the `Nullable Column Problem` that you describe. I understand that EF/TPH must make properties nullable if they are in derived types. The strange thing is that even properties in the base class are forced to be nullable. I cannot see why this must be, but The `Required()` method in the Fluent API is silently ignored.

Comment: No problem. Properties in the base class are not different from typical properties on entities, if they are reference types then you can use `Required` attribute or `IsRequired` method to make them non-nullable and I confirm that they both work :)